# C# TcpClient send data in other TCP frame

Tags: tcp, frame, tcpclient

I use `TCPClient` and `NetworkStream` to send short messages (Modbus frames) by socket. I use `Write()` method from `NetworkStream` to send data.

The problem is that I use twice or more `write()`, but the messages are send in one TCP Frame (check by Wireshark), for me is necessary that all writed messages will be sending in other TCP frame.

Any idea to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if TCP is buffering your data to optimize performance. You might want to put a delay between your two Sends or disable Nagel's algorithm (use SetSocketOption NoDelay true).

This can affect your TCP performance so you'll want to be careful when/where it's used.

Mike